# Assembly division by 0AH

Tags: assembly, hex

I'm working in assembly 386 and i keep dividing a number by 0Ah in a loop i keep getting a result that i cant understand here is my code:

```
MOV EAX,94Ch
MOV ten,0Ah;ten is of size DD that i've defined 
XOR ECX,ECX
L1:
CMP EAX,0;check if the number is zero
JE somewhere
DIV ten
INC CL
JMP L1
```

When there is **17h** in **EAX** and i divide by **0Ah** i get **CCCF** when i supposed to get **2** in EAX.
why is it like that?

Comment: What is the value in EDX?

Comment: I zero it out before the loop

Comment: I've fixed it by doing `XOR EDX,EDX` in the loop ,but why did this happen?

Comment: Read the documentation for `div`, it says there.

Answer (score 1):

The `DIV` instruction is a bit tricky, and to understand it, you need to look carefully at [the documentation](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html).

First, notice that your code is doing a 32-bit division. The way I know that is you have `DIV ten`, and `ten` is a DWORD (since you've declared it with `DD`). A DWORD is 32 bits.

From the above-linked documentation, we can see that a 32-bit division divides `EDX:EAX` by the operand (in this case, `ten`). It stores the quotient in `EAX`, and the remainder in `EDX`.

Okay, so wait a minute—what is `EDX:EAX`? This is a notation for a way to store a 64-bit value using two 32-bit registers. The high DWORD is in `EDX`, and the low DWORD is in `EAX`. Combine them together, and you get a 64-bit value.

Hopefully now you see why your solution of zeroing `EDX` worked, and why you were getting the wrong result without doing it. The division was actually implicitly using the `EDX` register as part of the dividend, so if it contains garbage, the result of the division will be wrong.

And now that you understand the problem, you can memorize this simple rule: whenever you do a 32-bit division, using the `DIV` instruction, *always* pre-zero the `EDX` register. The idiomatic and most efficient way to zero out a register is, of course, [with the `XOR` instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and).

Note that similar problem occurs with *signed* division ([`IDIV`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_137.html)), except that, in this case, you don't simply want to zero out `EDX`. You need to extend the value in `EAX` in a way that respects the *sign bit*. The [`CDQ` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_68.html) does this for you: it sign-extends `EAX` into `EDX:EAX`, ready for an `IDIV`. Another simple rule to learn—`CDQ` should virtually always precede `IDIV`.

---

A final bit of free optimization advice:

```
CMP EAX, 0
```

is equivalent to:

```
TEST EAX, EAX
```

but the latter assembles to fewer bytes of code (because it doesn't use an immediate operand) and is faster in many cases (both because of its smaller size and the fact that it is more likely to macro-fuse with the subsequent branch instruction, *e.g.* `JE`).

So another rule (isn't assembly programming fun?): when you are testing to see whether a register is 0, use `TEST` to bitwise-AND the register with itself.

The only time you would use `CMP xxx, 0` is when you want to see if a *memory* location is 0 (without first loading it into a register).